# Why does e.preventDefault() and return false not work on keydown event?

Tags: html

I just want to cancel the keydown event when I type the key except a number,

for this, I did the following :

```
function handleNum(obj){
    var e = window.event;
    var flag = true;

    if( ( e.keyCode >=  48 && e.keyCode <=  57 ) ||          
            ( e.keyCode >=  96 && e.keyCode <= 105 ) ||   
        e.keyCode ==   8 ||  
        e.keyCode ==  46 ||  
        //e.keyCode == 110 ||
        //e.keyCode == 190 ||
        e.keyCode ==  37 ||  
        e.keyCode ==  39 ||  
        e.keyCode ==  35 ||  
        e.keyCode ==  36 ||  
        e.keyCode ==   9     
    ) {
        flag = true;
    } else { 
        alert('You can type only a number!');
        console.log("doesn't return?");
                    e.preventDefault();
        flag = false;
    }
    console.log(flag);
    return flag;
}
```

html :

```
   <input type="text" onkeydown="return handleNum(this);" />
```

but It doesn't work, how can I solve this problems?
I have no idea why e.preventDefault() don't work in any browser.

Comment: `TypeError: e is undefined` Firebug

Comment: event is not handled .... need to set this condition in fuction, if (!e) var e = window.event, and pass the event from onkeydownevent

Answer (score 2):

Event is undefined, You can pass it like this

```
<script>
function handleNum(e,obj){
    if (!e) var e = window.event;

    var flag = true;

    if( ( e.keyCode >=  48 && e.keyCode <=  57 ) ||          
            ( e.keyCode >=  96 && e.keyCode <= 105 ) ||   
        e.keyCode ==   8 ||  
        e.keyCode ==  46 ||  
        //e.keyCode == 110 ||
        //e.keyCode == 190 ||
        e.keyCode ==  37 ||  
        e.keyCode ==  39 ||  
        e.keyCode ==  35 ||  
        e.keyCode ==  36 ||  
        e.keyCode ==   9     
    ) {
        flag = true;
    } else { 
        alert('You can type only a number!');
        console.log("doesn't return?");
        e.preventDefault();
        flag = false;
        obj.value = obj.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
    }
    console.log(flag);
    return flag;
}
</script>

<input type="text" onKeyDown="return handleNum(event,this);" />
```

**[Fiddle](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/Qhdaab)**

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code that will return false if the key pressed is not a number.

Use the `keypress event` instead of `keydown`.

```
$(fieldid).keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which<48 || e.which>57)) {
        return false;
    }
});
```